# name 'ticketType' is not defined

Tags: python

I have made the loop work so it can repeat itself for the given number of times. Although, I am not able to sum up the ticket costs and it is giving me an error

```
'ticketType' not defined
```

I have tried `ticketType = 0`, but the `totalCost` ends up being 0.

Heres the link for the python code: https://repl.it/repls/IrritatingBlankOs

```
print ('Welcome to RareCinema Ticketing System')
num = int(input('How many tickets would you like to buy?'))

def buyOneTicket() :
    ticketType = input('Enter the type of ticket (Child/Adult/Senior)?')
    movieType = input('Enter the movie type (2D/3D)?')
    return ticketCost
    return ticketType
    return movieType


ticketCost=0

if ticketType == ("child"):
    if movieType == ("2D"):
        ticketCost = 16
    elif movieType == ('3D'):
        ticketCost = 19 
elif ticketType == ('adult'):
    if movieType == ('2D'):
        ticketCost = 22
    elif movieType == ('3D'):
        ticketCost = 27
elif ticketType == ('senior'):
    if movieType == ('2D'):
        ticketCost = 14
    elif movieType == ('3D'):
        ticketCost = 18

count = 1
while (count <= num):
    ticketCost = ticketCost + buyOneTicket() 
    count = count + 1

print('Your total cost for ' + str(num) + ' is ', ticketCost)
```

Any idea why it is not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct program:

```
print ('Welcome to RareCinema Ticketing System')
num = int(input('How many tickets would you like to buy?'))

def buyOneTicket() :
        ticketType = input('Enter the type of ticket (Child/Adult/Senior)?')
        movieType = input('Enter the movie type (2D/3D)?')

        if ticketType == ("child"):
            if movieType == ("2D"):
                ticketCost = 16
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 19

        elif ticketType == ('adult'):
            if movieType == ('2D'):
                ticketCost = 22
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 27

        elif ticketType == ('senior'):
            if movieType == ('2D'):
                ticketCost = 14
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 18

        return ticketCost
ticketCost=0

count = 1
while (count <= num):
     ticketCost = ticketCost  + buyOneTicket() 
     count = count + 1
print('Your total cost for ' +str(num)+ ' is ', ticketCost )
```

I hope you can understand what is changed. Good luck !

Also you can write it shorter:

```
print ('Welcome to RareCinema Ticketing System')
num = int(input('How many tickets would you like to buy?'))
ticket = {("child", "2D"):16,("child", "3D"):19,
          ("adult", "2D"):22,("adult", "3D"):27,
          ("senior", "2D"):14,("senior", "3D"):18,}
def buyOneTicket() :
    ticketType = input('Enter the type of ticket (Child/Adult/Senior)?').lower()
    movieType = input('Enter the movie type (2D/3D)?').upper()
    return ticket[(ticketType, movieType)]

ticketCost=0
count = 1
while (count <= num):
    ticketCost = ticketCost  + buyOneTicket() 
    count = count + 1

print('Your total cost for ' +str(num)+ ' is ', ticketCost )
```

Comment: thankyou so much!! it works and honestly words cannot explain how happy I am :) thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

you define `TicketType` in the function definition, but then try to use it before actually calling the function which could return `TicketType` back to you. That's why it is not working.

either define it outside of the function or call the function first to get it returned.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention: There is also another mistake in your code!

You try to return three values in your function `buyOneTicket` (which should by the way be called `buy_one_ticket` to be more "pythonic" accordingly to [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#naming-conventions)):

```
def buyOneTicket() :
    ticketType = input('Enter the type of ticket (Child/Adult/Senior)?')
    movieType = input('Enter the movie type (2D/3D)?')
    return ticketCost
    return ticketType
    return movieType
```

The problem here is that the two lines after the first `return` will never be reached.

To return more than one value use so called [`tuples`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

```
def my_tuple_returning_function():
    value1 = 123
    value2 = "foo"
    value3 = "bar"
    return (value1, value2, value3)
```

Then you can unpack the tuple in the following way:

```
value1, value2, value3 = my_tuple_returning_function()
print("value1:", value1)
print("value2:", value2)
print("value3:", value3)
```